# how to customize the laravel login to add a universal key?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

how to overwrite laravel's login method, I want to add a universal key, to be able to enter the accounts of system users.

After making the login attempt and if it does not match the credentials of the database, make another attempt with a universal password that is in the code.

I think it is here (EloquentUserProvider) where the validation of credentials is done, but I do not know how to customize it so that it works as I wish.

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

I´m usising laravel 5.6

Comment: This is a HUGE security hole, and I would be absolutely horrified if I found out that a system I used implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Fired `sendFailedLoginResponse` method after failed login. You can overwrite it.

**Check `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in LoginController**

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
   if($this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request)) == 1){ //if first login attempt failed
      //implement your own login logic here with universal password 

   }else{
      throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
      ]);
   }
}
```